# How to make a star checkbox?

Tags: excel, vba

FYI - I'm a very fresh beginner.

I want to make a checkbox that looks like a star instead of a square. I want the star to be white as standard and turn Yellow on a single click. Next click it goes back to white. Simple as that.

I'm thinking of different ways to accomplish the same result, unfortunately I don't have the skills to make either one of them.

First I thought I would just create a checkbox form and in some way be able to change the square to a star-symbol. My Google-searches was giving me no help further on this path - maybe I wasn't accurate enough, I did however not find anything.

Secondly my idea was to just create a Yellow star symbol and make it clickable with a function, it's just that I don't know how to do just that.

Answer (score 4):

I've done this using two images for the backgrounds of labels (Used for the click event)

[image: Empty Star]
[image: Filled Star]

You can replace these with your own images. The images are then sized the same and positioned the same so that they overlap each other and the visible property of `FilledStar` to `False` by default and `True` for `EmptyStar`

The code behind my userform is then:

```
Private Sub EmptyStar_Click()
    Call StarClick
End Sub
Private Sub FilledStar_Click()
    Call StarClick
End Sub
Private Sub StarClick()
    Me.EmptyStar.Visible = Not Me.EmptyStar.Visible
    Me.FilledStar.Visible = Not Me.FilledStar.Visible
End Sub
```

This then gives the following output:

[image: Result]

Another option would be to have one image containing both images and move the position of the image so that only part of it is ever displayed at one time. This is a bit more complex in terms of moving/sizing the image correctly but would mean you only use one object instead of two.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of how it could work with a single Star per worksheet.

Place a Star Shape on your Sheet, set its fill color to white and paste the code below into a standard vba module.
Now assign the macro "ColorChangeShape" to the Star Shape by right clicking the shape and selecting "assign macro".

```
Sub ColorChangeShape()
ShpCol = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("5-Point Star 1")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB
If ShpCol = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
    ShpCol = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Else
    ShpCol = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End If
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("5-Point Star 1")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ShpCol
End Sub
```